# Hyperledger Blockchain Explorer cannot read block details

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-explorer

I have set up a fabric network (v1.1.0) on a Ubuntu 16.04 and use Blockchain Explorer to view details of transaction. Everything works fine but when I add new transaction to my network, Blockchain Explorer cannot scan the block from my network to insert into database and through this error:

> [ERROR] blockscanner - TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

```
[2018-05-30 02:30:11.684] [ERROR] Query - Error: No identity has been assigned to this client
    at Client._getSigningIdentity (/explorer/src/blockchain-explorer/node_modules/fabric-client/lib/Client.js:1207:11)
    at Client.queryInstalledChaincodes (/explorer/src/blockchain-explorer/node_modules/fabric-client/lib/Client.js:916:23)
    at helper.getOrgAdmin.then (/explorer/src/blockchain-explorer/app/query.js:127:18)
error: [client-utils.js]: sendPeersProposal - Promise is rejected: Error: 2 UNKNOWN: error executing chaincode: failed to execute transaction: timeout expired while executing transaction
    at new createStatusError (/explorer/src/blockchain-explorer/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:64:15)
    at /explorer/src/blockchain-explorer/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:583:15
error: [Channel.js]: Failed Query block. Error: Error: 2 UNKNOWN: error executing chaincode: failed to execute transaction: timeout expired while executing transaction
    at new createStatusError (/explorer/src/blockchain-explorer/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:64:15)
    at /explorer/src/blockchain-explorer/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:583:15
[2018-05-30 02:30:47.603] [ERROR] Query - Error: 2 UNKNOWN: error executing chaincode: failed to execute transaction: timeout expired while executing transaction
    at new createStatusError (/explorer/src/blockchain-explorer/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:64:15)
    at /explorer/src/blockchain-explorer/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:583:15
[2018-05-30 02:30:47.604] [ERROR] blockscanner - TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
    at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/explorer/src/blockchain-explorer/listener/blocklistener.js:29:30)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at saveBlockRange (/explorer/src/blockchain-explorer/service/blockscanner.js:60:23)
    at next (native)
    at onFulfilled (/explorer/src/blockchain-explorer/node_modules/co/index.js:65:19)
```

But when I erase all data in PostgreSQL of Blockchain Explorer and start explorer again it works fine?!
Does anyone get this error or know how to fix it?

My config file for explorer here:

```
{
"network-config": {
    "org1": {
        "name": "Org1",
        "mspid": "Org1MSP",
        "peer1": {
            "requests": "grpcs://peer0.org1.example.com:7051",
            "events": "grpcs://peer0.org1.example.com:7053",
            "server-hostname": "peer0.org1.example.com",
            "tls_cacerts": "/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt"
        },
        "peer2": {
            "requests": "grpcs://peer1.org1.example.com:8051",
            "events": "grpcs://peer1.org1.example.com:8053",
            "server-hostname": "peer1.org1.example.com",
            "tls_cacerts": "/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer1.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt"
        },
        "admin": {
            "key": "/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/keystore",
            "cert": "/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/signcerts"
        }
    }
},
"host": "localhost",
"port": "8080",
"channel": "my-channel",
"keyValueStore": "/tmp/fabric-client-kvs",
"eventWaitTime": "5000",
"pg": {
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "port": "5432",
    "database": "fabricexplorer",
    "username": "hppoc",
    "passwd": "password"
},
"license": "Apache-2.0"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Same issue, tried with 3 prior releases of explorer.

Comment: At present, I use release-3.2 branch of blockchain explorer this error not happen yet. You could try.